# PHP custom function code optimization

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

Now comes the hard part. How do you optimize this function:

```
function coin_matrix($test, $revs) {
    $coin = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($test); $i++) {
        foreach ($revs as $j => $rev) {
            foreach ($revs as $k => $rev) {
            if ($j != $k && 
                $test[$i][$j] != null && 
                $test[$i][$k] != null) {
                    if(!isset($coin[$test[$i][$j]])) {
                        $coin[$test[$i][$j]] = array(); 
                    }
                    if(!isset($coin[$test[$i][$j]][$test[$i][$k]])) {
                        $coin[$test[$i][$j]][$test[$i][$k]] = 0; 
                    }

                    $coin[$test[$i][$j]][$test[$i][$k]] += 1 / ($some_var - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $coin;
}
```

I'm not that good at this and if the arrays are large, it runs forever.

The function is supposed to find all pairs of values from a two-dim array and sum them like this: `$coin[$i][$j] += sum_of_pairs_in_array_row / [count(elements_of_row) - 1]`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm just trying to learn but thanks for the down-vote anyway.

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? Sometimes a code sample goes a long way, but sometimes a clear English description goes even further.

Comment: so many $ that looking at that i think I've won the jackpot... chaching

Comment: it computes a coincidence matrix for the Krippendorff's Alpha. the exact formula for each element of the array that the function is supposed to return is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krippendorff's_Alpha#Coincidence_matrices

each element of the returned matrix (array) is Ock and is computed according to the formula in the link above.

Comment: here is the unbroken link: http://bit.ly/bS9a92

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to be running all combinations of 3 items in the array, you are mostly stuck when it comes to large arrays. The main factor will be the fact that your function is cubic - you just can't do anything about the fact that, as input increases, output time will increase astronomically. You might be able to reduce the time to, say, 30% of where it is now, but if the time is already 3 weeks, 1 week of runtime does little for you.

That being said, you can still save yourself some effort inside the innermost loop. If I am interpreting your code correctly, you can set `$coin[$i][$j] = array()` just once per i-j combination, rather than check for each k item that it is not yet set.

That also being said, it's still not completely clear what the function is supposed to be doing, so I can't exactly offer other edits with confidence other than to use `$coin` instead of `coin`, to save the PHP parser a bit of effort.

Comment: There are still two, in the if statements.

Comment: yep, thanks! corrected also. see in the comments above for the description of the formula behind the function

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this wasn't pointed out earlier:
Change:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($test); $i++) {
```

To:

```
$count = count($test);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
```

Will save you quite some time. (more if $test is bigger)

I'm not sure if this is right, but it'd cause quite a slowdown as the $some_var doesn't exist:

```
$coin[$test[$i][$j]][$test[$i][$k]] += 1 / ($some_var - 1);
```

Finally, I'm still not sure what this is supposed to do. Maybe you can provide some good input and output values. As your stated purpose still doesn't make sense. What's $revs, why is it:

```
$coin[$i][$j] += sum_of_pairs_in_array_row / [count(elements_of_row) - 1]
```

instead of :

```
$coin[$row] += sum_of_pairs_in_array_row / [count(elements_of_row) - 1]
```

Comment: it computes a coincidence matrix for the Krippendorff's Alpha. the exact formula for each element of the matrix that the function is supposed to return is here: http://bit.ly/bS9a92 (wikipedia link).

$test is a bi-dimensional matrix, $revs is a vector and the keys from $revs coincide with the row number of $test